# Cant Connect mongodb-driver-async AtlasMongo DB

Tags: java, mongodb

Hello I'm facing some issues with to conect to my mongoDB using mongodb-driver-async

[image]

using:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
   <artifactId>mongodb-driver-async</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried several things and failed.

Attempt #1

```
ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://admin:XXXXXX@ac-bq9egvn-shard-00-00.1v58qfz.mongodb.net:27017,ac-bq9egvn-shard-00-01.1v58qfz.mongodb.net:27017,ac-bq9egvn-shard-00-02.1v58qfz.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-7z1zu9-shard-0&authSource=admin&w=majority");
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(connectionString);
```

Error #1

```
Unsupported stream type nio2 when SSL is enabled. Please use Netty instead
```

Attempt #2

```
ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://admin:admin@cluster0.1v58qfz.mongodb.net/?authSource=admin&authMechanism=MONGODB-CR");
```

Error #2

```
2023-04-12 10:42:15.549  INFO 20148 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[cluster0.1v58qfz.mongodb.net:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2023-04-12 10:42:15.667  INFO 20148 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0.1v58qfz.mongodb.net:27017
```

Attempt #3

```
ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://admin:<password>@ac-bq9egvn-shard-00-00.1v58qfz.mongodb.net:27017,ac-bq9egvn-shard-00-01.1v58qfz.mongodb.net:27017,ac-bq9egvn-shard-00-02.1v58qfz.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-7z1zu9-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority");
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(connectionString).build();
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

Error #3

[image]

I need to do asynchronous database insert operations, so this is the motivation for using this driver.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: mongodb-driver-async is [unmaintained](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-async). What happens when you use [the maintained driver?](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-reactivestreams)